# Zend View external url appended to site url

Tags: zend-framework

The zend framework appends all url's without a 'http' prexix to the page url.

E.g. http://site.com/www.anothersite.com

How can I get it to just appear at www.anothersite.com without the http?

This is happening for url's that are in a hard coded anchor without dynamic content. I could add http to the url, but there must be a solution to having links begin with www?

Comment: The output link will be <a href="www.mysite.com/www.anothersite.com">link</a>

It is not using the url helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make a normal HTML link like that :

```
<a href="http://www.someothersite.com">www.someothersite.com</a>
```

There is no use for the `URL` view helper here since it is outside of the content managed by Zend and therefore, you don't have to comply with the `router`

Comment: I have a link like the one above but it will generate the output to be:

<a href="www.someothersite.com">http://mysite.com/www.someothersite.com</a>

Comment: Its an HTML problem, you must have the `HTTP://` in the `href` attribute of the tag `a` or it will be considered as a relative link and not an absolute one like you want to do